# How to assign decimal to variable on windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, command, substring, echo

`echo %time:~-5%` returns a 5-character string, such as
`18.09`

However, i cannot seem to set that string to a variable:

```
set start =  %time:~-5%
echo %start%
```

returns
`10:07:18.09`

what's simple way to get those last 5 chars into a variable?

thx

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. However, make sure that there are no spaces to the left/right of the `=` assignment operator, i.e. `set start=%time:~-5%`. Also bear in mind, that the formatting of the decimal separator is subject to the current locale.

Comment: @IInspectable, that's the issue: spaces. If you submit as answer, i'll mark as answer. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't like space next to `=`. So try this ...

```
set start=%time:~-5%
echo %start%
```